# Dart Vision Client Library

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am developing an app that uses an OCR,
I used offline **Firebase ML Vision** so far but it is limited in terms it can't read Cyrillic letters.
**Google Cloud Vision** seems to fix that problem.
But my app is built with Flutter and Dart, and Vision does not have a client library for Dart.
These are the [available libraries](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries).
Did I miss something?

Comment: Looks like it part of the googleapis package? https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything, Google cloud does not have an official client library for dart [1]. However, I found a GitHub tread that may help you [2] developing the OCR for Cyrillic letters.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries

[2] https://github.com/dart-lang/googleapis/issues/67